# Typescript: overwrite Record value type in another type

Tags: typescript, typescript-types, typescript-utility

Imagine I have the following interface defined:

```
export interface BaseInterface {
    foo?: Record<string, SomeType>;
    bar?: Record<string, SomeOtherType>;
    ... // Many more fields like this
}
```

I want to create a new type, which will be equivalent to `BaseInterface`, except all record types should be wrapped in `Partial` like this:

```
export type MyType = {
    foo?: Record<string, Partial<SomeType>>;
    bar?: Record<string, Partial<SomeOtherType>>;
    ...
}
```

I don't want to manually write the new interface, because there are too many fields in the base interface + there are multiple interfaces that I need to overwrite like this, so I would like to find out if there is a way to achieve the same result using some TypeScript magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional type to extract the record value type and make that partial. We can then use a mapped type to apply to all properties:

```
type RecordValuePartial<T> = T extends Record<string, infer V>? Record<string, Partial<V>>: T
type AllRecordValuePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: RecordValuePartial<T[P]>
}


export type MyType = AllRecordValuePartial<BaseInterface> // Same as: 
// export type MyTypeManual = {
//     foo?: Record<string, Partial<SomeType>> | undefined;
//     bar?: Record<string, Partial<SomeOtherType>>| undefined ;
    
// }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXNAvFA3gWAFBRQDOAXMcAE4CWAdgOZT4C++oksiEA8sABYQVU7TLgJQARmSKVaDZvggAPMHArAotYAIBmAQwDG0AEK6iEAJI0tFPYez5ChbXDgB+MgCUI+1QBMAPNLU9AA0HEhCEAB8ANwOjuK6FO5QXj4UAUGyYfBIPPyCaLEO8nisaKnefgBqugA2AK4QAApJwFT1-shRUJjIUEpaNL5ElemZMqEaNNoCUNVRrmN+gZN0Ya1qHXX+C1FkyOXsAIJ1dWk19U2b7Z3dvfZiANrN01AA1hAgcNpQyAC6niqGVqjRabW2XRe-yipXwCmUqnUbGgAFkQJEHqdzsDfKDrhDOiYzJZrLZolAAPSU2C6JBQUxkfDUgaItRQFFQdGRVG6GgNeoPUQsxxQZxuIHjVbBdZQG6Q3IoIo9AA+UAawwg2loEF8cTwIoSSRSFwy0uycsJO0V+QEkSiUTVGt8Wp1vig+tFzJpTCAA)